# Riemann integrability of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> The function $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined to be $f(x) = |x|$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $f(x)=0$ if $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Is $f$ integrable? Why?

My attempt was:

$f$ has infinite points of discontinuity. And since $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is not countable, we cannot find a partition $P_n$ such that $U(P_n, f) - L(P_n, f) \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$. Hence $f$ is not integrable.

Is this correct? Would it be another way of proving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed correct, but, unless you've proven it earlier, it is not obvious why an uncountable set of points of discontinuity implies the non-integrability of a function. The way I'd go about it without using the countability criterion would be as follows:

Lets first assume that $0\notin [a,b]$. Without loss of generality, we can say $0 < a$ because, if $b<0$ we apply the same argument on $-f$. This means that on $[a,b] f(x)=x$ for all rational points $x$. Let $P=\{x_0, x_1,...x_n\}$ be an arbitrary partition. Since for any $k\in\{1,2,...,n\}$ there exists an irrational number in the interval $I_k:=(x_{k-1},x_k)$ the infimum of $f$ on that set must be $0$ (since there are no values of $f$ less than $0$). Similarily, because the set $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ there must also be a rational number in the interval $I_k$. This implies that the supremum of $f$ on $I_k$ must be greater than or equal to that rational number, which is obviously greater than or equal to $a$. This means that $L(P,f)=0$ and $U(P,f)\geq a(b-a)$ for any partition $P$. Meaning that their difference is greater than or equal to $a$. This implies the sequence of differences from your question cant converge to zero (if it converges, then it converges to a number $\geq a > 0$).

To solve for the case $0\in[a,b]$ notice that it suffices to prove that the function isn't Riemann integrable on some subset of $[a,b]$. And a closed subinterval of $[a,b]$ that doesnt contain $0$ must exist.